# So where do I start learning about Cyber Sec?

Tags: professional-education, defense, secure-coding

I'm an 11th grader interested in the whole field/world of IS and what not so I decided to look around this site and various others, and I have come to the conclusion that I have no clue where I am to start.

I would like to learn more about IS and in the near(not so near) future and go along a route leading to security engineering or something of the sort, but there are so many different fields and specifications and just stuff, and I quite frankly am not sure where would be a relatively good place to start my search for *knowledge*.

Comment: This question may be a bit too broad/opinion based for StackExchange, but from personal experience I would say that cybersecurity is very hands-on and so competitions are a great way to get introduced to the field. There are many that are specifically aimed at the high school level; check out picoCTF, HSCTF, EasyCTF, angstromCTF, sCTF, etc. Also look at ctftime.org for a full calendar of these competitions.

Answer (score -3):

if you ask me, of course i'll tell you read a lot about IT.
because IT world is so big, and also create more IT field so cant list on by one at here. 
most important is be realistic, dont idealize. focus on one field.

Comment: Welcome! Your answer needs more substance. As is, it would make a better comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55886/discussion-on-answer-by-billy-sutomo-so-where-do-i-start-learning-about-cyber-se).